# CSS cutting off the end of an input box

Tags: css

I have a form that has two fields being cut off, there is an `overflow:hidden;` in there which I've turned off on Firebug but that only works for the "enter password" input and not the "confirm password" input. Can anyone track down why it's still cutting off the box?

Here's the [link](http://www.teamworksdesign.com/clients/rwcmd/login/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is on two lines of forms.css, 206:

```
.gform_wrapper .field_name_first input, .gform_wrapper .ginput_complex .ginput_left input {
width: 93% !important;
}
```

and 238:

```
.gform_wrapper .ginput_complex .ginput_right input, .gform_wrapper .ginput_complex .ginput_right select {
width: 90% !important;
}
```

Set the widths to the ones above and it should solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

The div with the id `input_1_10_container` (surrounding both password fields) is cutting it with `overflow:hidden`

Answer (score 1):

Try to decrease horizontal padding or width for both inputs. It is rather bad idea to mix percent/absolute values for element dimension properties

Answer (score 1):

adjust the width accordingly, like

```
.gform_wrapper .ginput_complex {
width: 614px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.gform_wrapper .ginput_complex {overflow:hidden}
```

on line 202 of your css has an overflow hidden.. turning that off solved the issue here.
I'd personally recommend you reduce the width of both fields, guess it'll look a bit better and solve the issue too.. Just a thought..

Answer (score 0):

remove the overflow: hidden from the `.gform_wrapper .ginput_complex .ginput_left, .gform_wrapper .ginput_complex .ginput_right, .gform_wrapper .ginput_complex .ginput_full` and add margin-right: 10px on `.gform_wrapper .ginput_complex .ginput_left`

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need the two spans...

You could do something like this (here is inline, just code this as css)

```
<div class="ginput_complex ginput_container" id="input_1_10_container">
   <input style="width: 45% !important; display:inline-block; margin-right:12px;"
          type="password"  placeholder="Enter Password" 
          name="input_10" id="input_1_10" value="" tabindex="5">      
   <label style="display: none;" for="input_1_10">Enter Password</label>

   <input style="width: 45% !important; display: inline-block;" 
          type="password"  placeholder="Confirm Password" name="input_10_2" 
          id="input_1_10_2" value="" tabindex="6">
   <label style="display: none;" for="input_1_10_2">Confirm Password</label>
</div>
```

that works with enlargments of the text too.

Try substituting this with Firebug to your div...

Answer (score 0):

This code worked

```
.gform_body input,textarea,select {box-sizing:border-box !important;}

#input_1_10_1_container {width:48.5% !important;}
#input_1_10_2_container {width:48.5%;float:left}
```